# Add a character to a specific duplicate string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to add a character to a specific duplicate string, like in the following situation:

`nomes_comp = ['Fulano A', 'Beltrano B', 'Fulano A']`

So I have duplicate items on my list; I would like to add another character in one of the duplicate items, hoping to get the following output:

`nomes_comp = ['Fulano A', 'Beltrano B', 'Fulano A1']`

I'm trying this way, but it's not working:

```py
for nome in zip(nomes[0], nomes[1]):
   nomes_comp.append(nome[0] + ' ' + nome[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary (or a `collections.defaultdict`) to keep track of how many occurrences you've found.

```
nomes_comp = ['Fulano A', 'Beltrano B', 'Fulano A']

count_d = dict()

for i, n in enumerate(nomes_comp):
    c = count_d.get(n, 0)
    count_d[n] = c + 1
    if c:
        nomes_comp[i] = n + str(c)
```

After you do this, the original `nomes_comp` is modified to:

```
['Fulano A', 'Beltrano B', 'Fulano A1']
```

Comment: Glad to help, @Pedro [Since you're new here, please upvote any answers that you find helpful, and accept the answer that best answers your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
nomes_comp = ["Fulano A", "Beltrano B", "Fulano A"]

out, cnt = [], {}
for n in nomes_comp:
    if n in cnt:
        cnt[n] += 1
        out.append(f"{n}{cnt[n]}")
    else:
        cnt[n] = 0
        out.append(n)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Fulano A', 'Beltrano B', 'Fulano A1']
```

Comment: Hey Andrej, thanks for your answer. But I used Pranav's solution, and I tried yours, but I'm my case, I need to modify the list and not create another. But I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(nomes_comp)
for name, count in counts:
    if count > 1:
        ...
```

Generate and store a new unique name for such entries.

Comment: Hey J_Hm, thanks for answering. Actually, I'm very new to python programming, so the answer it's a bit difficult for me. If you have time and can explain, I would like to test it.